# How do I present a single row of a PySpark dataframe vertically in Jupyter notebook output?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

Have a need to display certain wide tables - single result vertically to be able to examine the record.

If I have code like the following:

```
def get_fiscal_df():
    q = "select * from fiscal_records where id = 'R20210106'"
    df = spark.sql(q)

df = get_fiscal_df()
df.show() # this would be replaced by new code/method
```

Is there something I could do (idiomatic) to show that would display that data like so:

| Field Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| id | R20210106 |
| field2 | value2 |
| field3 | value3 |
| field4 | value4 |
| field5 | value5 |

The only difference being I have inherited some tables that are 250 to 300 fields wide.

Comment: `df.show(vertical=True)`?

Comment: You should post that as an answer, @mck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.show(vertical=True)` to display the dataframe in vertical format, with each row/record having its own table.